# Adding a string containing XML to a SOAPElement with Java

Tags: java, xml, soap

I have to send data from an excel file as an XML to a webservice. The data in the table looks kinda like this:
[see example of table here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEOTi.png)

The first row always contains the XML-tag for the data of the column. Most of the data columns only hold strings, but some have xml. Those child-nodes are important for the Webservice to accept the data.

I'm working with SOAP, creating a new SOAPElement for each column, where every row is a new SOAP request.

```
SOAPElement newElement = body.addChildElement(tagForThisColumn);
newElement.addTextNode(stringValueOfCell);
```

This works perfectly for the string values, but the SOAPElement escapes all the "<" and ">" of the cells with xml.

I already searched for an answer and found some solutions to similar problems, but none fit mine..

Answer (score 3):

You should add a Node to the SoapElement.
I have done something similar by adding a SAML Token to a SoapElement in the soap header:

```
SOAPHeader header = envelope.addHeader();

SOAPElement security = header.addChildElement("Security", "wsse",
    "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");

DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
File file = new File("your-file.xml");

/* parse existing file to DOM */
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new FileInputStream(file));

Document securityDoc = security.getOwnerDocument();
Node newNode = securityDoc.importNode(document.getFirstChild(), true);

//Add the Node
security.appendChild(newNode);
```

I hope it is useful.

Comment: This is unrelated to the thread but I am not sure how I can reach you otherwise. There is currently an add "Meet our team" on the right panel of the Cross Validated site. Your profile picture (or rather a mini movie) is very distracting to me. It is the only part of the screen that is not still, and it really catches my attention, making it hard to focus on the site's content. Would you mind temporarily disabling the movie and just keeping a still picture instead while the add is on and your profile picture is displayed there? Thank you! And sorry for disturbing you.