# how to add <soap:Envelope> and <soap:body> in xml request

Tags: java, webservice-client

```
how to add <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> in xml soap request.
```

My sample request is given below.I created jaxb annotated classes and        marshalled the object to xml format ,but i need to add above soap envlope and     body in request before sending request to server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<StatusRequest>
<AccountID>231</AccountID>
<PassPhrase>sddddd</PassPhrase>
<StatusList>
<PICNumber>111111</PICNumber>
</StatusList>
<Test>Y</Test>
</StatusRequest>
```

Please provide sample program.

Comment: Do you use any WS API? Like Axis/Axis2/CXF/JAX-WS?

Answer (score 4):

Use a javax.xml.soap.

You need to get a Document from the object you want to put inside the envelope (marshal it with JAXB, in the example) an put it in the body.

This way:

```
MessageFactory mfactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = mfactory.createMessage();
SOAPBody soapBody = petition.getSOAPBody();
soapBody.addDocument(marshaller.marshallDoc(obj));
soapMessage.saveChanges();
```

This way when you do:

```
soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
```

You will see SOAP part in the output.

Comment: using your above example, do I also do the same to add marshalled header to soapBody?

Comment: @Angelina sorry for the long delay...
Well, I haven't done what you say before so I have no examples, but I think that he first response in this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041430/adding-a-string-containing-xml-to-a-soapelement-with-java , he does the same but has to generate a SOAPElement before

Comment: What is the type of `marshaller` object? I can't find anything with `marshallDoc` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
// Obtain SOAP Part

SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
// Obtain Envelope from SOAP Part

SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
// Obtain Header from Envelope

SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
// Obtain Body from Envelope

QName headerName = new QName("namespaceURI", "localPart");
// SOAPHeaderElement must have an associated QName object.

SOAPHeaderElement headerElement = header.addHeaderElement(headerName);
// Create new SOAPHeaderElement object initialized with the specified Qname
// and add it to this SOAPHeader object.

headerElement.addAttribute(new QName("localPart"), "valueToAdd");
// Add attribute to header  

 QName bodyName = new QName("namespaceURI", "localPart");
// SOAPBodyElement must have an associated QName object.

SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = body.addBodyElement(bodyName);
// Add Body Element
```

You might this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhr.html) and corresponding JavaDocs for SAAJ.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that `req` is a class marked by `javax.xml.bind.annotation`, then:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.newDocument();
marshaller.marshal(req, doc);

MessageFactory mfactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = mfactory.createMessage();
SOAPBody soapBody = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();
soapBody.addDocument(doc);

var baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
soapMessage.writeTo(baos);
var str = new String(baos.toByteArray(), Charset.forName("UTF8"));
log.info("SOAPMessage: {}", str);
```